# Add private framework to theos project without xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak, theos

I am working on an application which can help the user to kill all background processes. I have tried to use the private framework Blackboard services to use this code:

```
BKSTerminateApplicationForReasonAndReportWithDescription(@"com.apple.mobilesafari", 5, 1, @"Kill safari");
```

But when i make my project it is countered an error like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_BKSTerminateApplicationGroupForReasonAndReportWithDescript‌ion", referenced from: _main in main.mm.f37d78b2.o
```

**This is my step:**

1. Add the header of private framework
2. Call the function BKSTerminateApplicationGroupForReasonAndReportWithDescript‌ion on main.mm

**And it is countered the above error. Furthermore, I have tried to:**

1. Add the private framework to my project by add this to my makefile file: 
   `appname_Private_Frameworks =  BackBoardServices` 
   But this counter the error: Can not find the framework
2. Dynamic load the private framework but it is not work too.

Anyone point me out please!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? Thanks

Comment: @MiroslavKovac no i dont, if you have please help me